# What is the best way to read huge data file that is larger than RAM in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-mapping, bigdata

I need to work with huge data matrix file that is larger than available RAM. For example, the matrix has 2500 rows and 1 million columns, which leads to ~20 GB. Basically I only need to read the data into memory, no writing operation at all.

I thought [memory mapping](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html) would work. But it turned out that's not very efficient as the RAM would blow up. This is because the OS will always automatically cache the data (pages) into memory until the RAM is full. After that, as in data-larger-than-RAM case, there will be page faults, hence page-in and page-out process, which is essentially disk-read/write and slows the speed.

I need to point out that I would also want to randomly read some subset of data, say just Row 1000 to 1500 and Column 1000 to 5000.

**[EDIT]**

**The data file is a txt file, and well formatted like a matrix. Basically, I need read in the big data matrix, and do crossproduct with another vector column by column.**

**[END EDIT]**

My questions are:

1. are their other alternative approaches? Could direct reading chunk-by-chunk be better?
2. Or is there a smart way to programmatically free up page caches before RAM is full in memory mapping? I just think it might be better if we could page out data from memory before RAM is full.
3. Is there a way to read data file column-by-column?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It all depends on what you're doing with it and what format.

Comment: I need read in the big data matrix, and do crossproduct with another vector column by column. @SteveWellens, so I thought database might not be the best choice.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, it's a text file and well formatted as a matrix format.

Comment: With line indexing you could read in just what's required for each calculation at a time.

Comment: for column-by-column reading i would store a transposed copy of the matrix. it would be slow for construction but useful for later uses.

Comment: How about preprocessing the file into a more convenient structure?
Say into a binary format, with 256x256 submatrix blocks stored sequentially. --- Also, is there really a problem due to the caching?

Comment: @DanMašek, yes I noticed the memory blowed up to its upper limit. I assume this is due to caching since OS would automatically keeps caching data into memory. If not caching, would there be any other possible reasons?

Comment: If it uses all the unused memory for cached data that's not really a problem in itself. It shouldn't lead to any paging since the system knows it can drop stuff from the cache when it needs more "real" memory. And while it doesn't need more "real" memory it can as well use all the unused memory for caching.

Comment: @AaronZeng Yes, but what I mean is... did you measure that as being the bottleneck? I was also going to mention what _sth_ said.

Comment: @AaronZeng what platform do you use? On Linux there is big difference between MAP_SHARED and MAP_PRIVATE